# Cloud 9 Trouble getting on to the rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide, cloud9

[gemfile here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SEz9.jpg) I'm new to coding and having trouble connecting to the rails server on cloud 9. I keep getting this  error message, How do I resolve this issue? ]
!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `resource' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /home/ubuntu/workspace/blog/Gemfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------

> resource 'https://rubygems.org'

Comment: Try my answer below and let me know if it still have an error.

Comment: You should try `source` not `resource`.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, instead of:

```
resource 'https://rubygems.org'
```

It should be:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: So, the error is the same? `Undefined local variable or method `resource' for Gemfile`

Comment: after changing the gemfile did you run bundle install?

Comment: yes, just tried that I got nothing. still an error message

Comment: So, what's the error? I don't believe that you still got the same error posted above.

Comment: sorry for not posting the error message. this is what I keep getting http://imgur.com/QsrMiUp

Comment: Never mind I just uninstalled everything. Then reinstalled, works fine now. Thanks